# Failed to construct kafka producer: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers (Intermittent issue)

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I am getting intermittent issues while accessing the kafka service from the Kubernetes pod.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:432)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at oracle.fs.framework.core.transports.event.kafka.KafkaFactory.createProducer(KafkaFactory.java:29)
    at oracle.fs.framework.core.transports.event.kafka.stream.KafkaStreamEventTransport.start(KafkaStreamEventTransport.java:165)
    at oracle.fs.framework.core.service.TransportLifecycleHandler.start(TransportLifecycleHandler.java:57)
    at oracle.fs.framework.core.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:400)
    at oracle.fs.foundation.bootstrap.Bootstrap.startDomain(Bootstrap.java:555)
    at oracle.fs.foundation.bootstrap.Bootstrap.startDomain(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at oracle.fs.foundation.bootstrap.Bootstrap.startDomain(Bootstrap.java:147)
    at oracle.fs.foundation.bootstrap.Bootstrap.startDomain(Bootstrap.java:102)
    at oracle.fs.service.driver.DomainServiceDriver.startService(DomainServiceDriver.java:24)
    at oracle.fs.service.driver.DomainServiceDriver.main(DomainServiceDriver.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:407)
```

I am not sure which causes this issue intermittently as I've found the bootstrap urls are correct.

Comment: Sounds like you have an unstable network

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is there any possible issue related to the kube-dns? I didn't find any related issue in kube-dns logs. What is your best guess for this issue?

Comment: Are you running Kafka brokers in k8s? Assuming you are trying to connect to something like `kafka namespace.svc.cluster.local`, then it's possible, yes .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I had a docker running with kafka frameworks and my application couldn't connect to the brocker.
I changed my /etc/hosts to understand 127.0.0.1 for my bootstrap sevice alias (confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.9)

Answer (score -1):

Its the Format of spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=port:9092
sample: spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092 or spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092, etc

Comment: can you elaborate? I am not sure I understand your answer